# Comment traduire « kick-start your ... career » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique

> Kick-Start Your Graphic Design Career.

Le contexte c'est que c'est dans une offre de stage destinée à des étudiants. On peut voir que le verbe (*to kick-start*) pourrait signifier [démarrer rapidement/bien](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/kick-start), [donner une nouvelle impulsion](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/kick-start) à quelque chose, [commencer en beauté](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kick_start#Translations_2), (re)[lancer](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kick_start#Translations_2), [faire repartir](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/kick-start/590699). Parfois [*jump-start*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/jump-start) (revitaliser) est présenté comme synonyme. Le substantif (le *kick-start*) pour l'impulsion au coeur de la relance pourrait être traduit par [*coup de fouet*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kick_start#English). Ça diffère cependant du verbe [*to kick-off*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/kick_off), *donner le coup d'envoi*, quoique le coup d'envoi se soit au début de la partie, un peu comme l'est par analogie la carrière d'un stagiaire il me semble.

Comment préfère-t-on traduire la phrase (« Kick-Start Your Graphic Design Career ») et pourquoi ?

Answer (score 4):

Je dirais "Lancer votre carrière de designer graphique" pour conserver la notion de démarrage énergique.

- "Démarrer rapidement" pourrait fonctionner mais n'est pas aussi concis que "Lancer"
- "Donner une nouvelle impulsion"/"relancer"/"faire repartir" impliquerait que la carrière a déjà debuté
- "Commencer en beauté" n'est pas assez formel

Answer (score 3):

Quelques propositions...

2 assez classique et neutres (peut-être un peu vieillottes) :

> Démarrez votre carrière [de designer] en trombe

> Démarrez votre carrière [de designer] sur les chapeaux de roues

Une autre utilisant un terme anglais, mais plus commun à mon sens. Le démarrage rapide est implicite, c'est le but des starting-blocks :

> Dans les starting-blocks pour votre carrière [de designer]

Un autre un peu barbare mais je pense assez commune, un peu plus "jeune" aussi je trouve :

> Boostez votre début de carrière [de designer]

Comment: Le terme "booster" est très bon et se retrouve beaucoup dans différentes annonces sur les réseaux comme LinkedIn, mais je trouve qu'il renvoie une idée d'"accélération" de quelque chose d'existant, plutôt que d'un vrai lancement à partir de zéro. C'est mon opinion en tout cas. :)

Comment: Le début de carrière, pour moi, c'est le lancement, on booste ce lancement.

Comment: Synonymes de [_booster_](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=boost&id=3585)